# Send array of objects attach files in POST request to Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, post, multipartform-data

I'm a newbie Front-End developer.

I should build a API to send an array of object, and each object contains many files, structure like below:

```js
{
   files: [
      file: (binary),
      name: "file name",
      description: "description",
      attachments: [
         attachment(binary), 
         ...
      ]
      ...
   ],
   infor: {
      name: "Name",
      address: "address"
   }
}
```

And our back-end server is wrote by Django. My JS Code:

```js
    generateFormData() {
        const originData = store.getState().quotation;
        let formData = new FormData();
        let user = originData.user;
        Object.keys(originData.files).forEach((key, index) => {
            const file = originData.files[key];
            const surfare_option = (file.surface_otpion && file.surface_otpion.id) ? file.surface_otpion.id : null;
            const color_option = (file.color_option && file.color_option.id) ? file.color_option.id : null;
            formData.append(`files[${index}]`, file.file);
            formData.append(`files[${index}][quantity]`, file.quantity);
            formData.append(`files[${index}][material]`, (file.material.id) ? (file.material.id) : null);
            formData.append(`files[${index}][material_type]`, (file.materialType.id) ? (file.materialType.id) : null);
            formData.append(`files[${index}][surface_option]`, surfare_option);
            formData.append(`files[${index}][color_option]`, color_option);
            formData.append(`files[${index}][tolerance]`, file.tolerances);
            formData.append(`files[${index}][contain_thread]`, file.containThreads);
            formData.append(`files[${index}][description]`, file.description)
            if (file.attachments.length > 0) {
                file.attachments.forEach((attactment, att_index) => {
                    formData.append(`files[${index}][attachments][${att_index}]`, attactment);
                });
            } else {
                formData.append(`files[${index}][attachments]`, []);
            }
        });
        formData.append(`g_captcha`, originData.captcha);
        formData.append('user[first_name]', user.first_name);
        formData.append('user[last_name]', user.last_name);
        formData.append('user[phone]', user.phone);
        formData.append('user[address]', user.address);
        formData.append('user[email]', user.email);
        return formData;
    }

    sendData() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const formData = this.generateData();
            let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
                if (xhttp.readyState === 4 && xhttp.status === 200) {
                    resolve(JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText));
                }
                if (xhttp.readyState === 4 && xhttp.status !== 200) {
                    reject(this.handleError(xhttp));
                }
            };
            xhttp.upload.onloadstart = (e) => {
                this.setState((state, props) => {
                    state.uploadStatus = 'UPLOADING';
                    return state;
                });
            }
            xhttp.upload.onprogress = (e) => {
                this.setState((state, props) => {
                    state.uploadProgress = Math.floor((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);
                    return state;
                });
            }

            // xhttp.open('POST', UPLOAD_URL, true);
            xhttp.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/content/get-new-quotation', true);
            xhttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', `Token ${document.getElementById('auth_token').value}`);
            xhttp.send(formData);
        });
    }
```

And when i print ***request.data** on server, i see this:

```
<QueryDict: {'files[0][quantity]': ['1'], 'files[0][material]': ['null'], 'files[0][material_type]': ['null'], 'files[0][surface_option]': ['null'], 'files[0][color_option]': ['null'], 'files[0][tolerance]': ['false'], 'files[0][contain_thread]': ['false'], 'files[0][description]': ['Electronic enclosure of low production run sensor. The 
part was anodized and marked according to the specifications.'], 'files[0][attachments]': [''], 'files[1][quantity]': ['1'], 'files[1][material]': ['null'], 'files[1][material_type]': ['null'], 'files[1][surface_option]': ['null'], 'files[1][color_option]': ['null'], 'files[1][tolerance]': ['false'], 'files[1][contain_thread]': ['false'], 'files[1][description]': ['Electronic enclosure of low production run sensor. The part was anodized and marked according to the specifications.'], 'files[1][attachments]': [''], 'files[0]': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: 746821 - Copy.x_t (application/octet-stream)>], 'files[1]': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: 746821 - Copy.x_t (application/octet-stream)>]}>
```

I tried to find solution to server can get data from above QueryDict. But our Back-End developer doesn't allow that solution, he want I send data so that when he print request.data on server, data appear Raw JSON (He just test by Postman)

```
{
'files': [
   {
      'file': (binary), 
      'name': 'name', 
      'description': 'description', 
      'attachments': ['attachment']
   },
   {
      'file': (binary),
      ...
   }
]
}
```

To help he can use **request.data.files[0].name or request.data.files[0].attachments[0]** .v.v...

I don't really sure about that requirement because i need use form-data send file data, no JSON, so **please help me! Is it possible? If it is possible, how to build?**

Sorry about my bad english :(

Comment: that a weird task to get files from `request.data` , does he know that he can just get files from any `POST` request with `request.FILES` ?

Comment: That is not the point, he want use request.data or request.post like a json. 
Example: request.data.files[0] = { file: file, name: 'name', .... };